# Elmah Page restriction in Asp net forms C#

Tags: asp.net

this is my configuration for elmah in web.config

```
 <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" 
         path="elmah.axd" 
         type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </httpHandlers>


  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Dev" />
    <deny users="*" />  
  </authorization>

</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ELMAH" 
         verb="POST,GET,HEAD" 
         path="elmah.axd" 
         type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" 
         preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

But how do tell that I'm a Dev ? I'm using Session for cookies but I don't know how can i tell that i'm an admin or user

Comment: Did you check out this: https://blog.elmah.io/elmah-security-and-allowremoteaccess-explained/?

Comment: Thanks but after searching i learned that I had to create a Global.asax and make a function so it can detect the roles from the FormsValidation Ticket